# Notepad++ hinting on CSS3 property fields

Tags: css, autocomplete, notepad++

Is there a way to get Notepad++ to display hint for CSS property fields?

Settings->Preferences - Auto-Completion - "Function parameters hint on input" only seems to work for functions--which do not exist in CSS.

I can complete "box-sha" with + but box-shadow fields do not appear like "Function parameters hint on input" does for functions!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `langs.xml` file, which is what handles the highlighting.
I found a patch [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/patches/329/) or a new plugin on github [HERE](https://github.com/marvinlabs/notepad-plus-plus-scss-syntax-highlighting). I hope this help.

Comment: These only autocomplete the properties.  It does not display hints for their fields.  Such as `box-shadow` having `horizontal vertical [blur] [spread] [color] [inset]`

Answer (score 0):

I manually add the my most forgotten syntax.

1) Open Notepad++/plugins/APIs

2) Create new file "css.xml"

3) Edit the "css.xml" like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
    <AutoComplete>
        <KeyWord name="background: url(&quot;&quot;) no-repeat center center fixed;" />
        <KeyWord name="background-size: cover;" />
        <KeyWord name="border-top-left-radius: 4px;" />
        <KeyWord name="border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;" />
        <KeyWord name="border-top-right-radius: 4px;" />
        <KeyWord name="border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;" />
        <KeyWord name="box-shadow: [h-shadow]px [v-shadow]px [blur]px red;" />
    </AutoComplete>
</NotepadPlus>
```

In other words, this method just behave like snippets tool.